# Deployement problems using Eclipse +OC4J

Tags: eclipse, oc4j, oas

I am using OC4J from within Eclipse.

I am deploying to the OC4J server using Eclipse too.

Unfortunately, the deployment once succeed and once give me the following error (which is a boring behavior):

```
10/11/30 12:00:47 WARNING: ApplicationUnDeployer.removeFiles WARNING: Unable to remove appDir D:\sources\jdv10-4\j2ee\home\applications\MyApp : Unable to remove D:\sources\jdv10-4\j2ee\home\applications\MyAppjava.io.IOException: Unable to remove D:\sources\jdv10-4\j2ee\home\applications\MyApp
    at oracle.oc4j.util.FileUtils.recursiveRemove(FileUtils.java:262)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.ApplicationUnDeployer.removeFiles(ApplicationUnDeployer.java:194)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.ApplicationUnDeployer.doUndeploy(ApplicationUnDeployer.java:163)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.UnDeployerBase.execute(UnDeployerBase.java:91)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.UnDeployerBase.execute(UnDeployerBase.java:72)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.ApplicationDeployer.undeployPrevious(ApplicationDeployer.java:282)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.ApplicationDeployer.doDeploy(ApplicationDeployer.java:177)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.DeployerBase.execute(DeployerBase.java:93)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.jmx.server.mbeans.deploy.OC4JDeployerRunnable.doRun(OC4JDeployerRunnable.java:52)
    at oracle.oc4j.admin.jmx.server.mbeans.deploy.DeployerRunnable.run(DeployerRunnable.java:81)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)

2010-11-30 12:00:47.149 NOTIFICATION Application UnDeployer for MyApp COMPLETES.
2010-11-30 12:00:47.164 NOTIFICATION Initialize D:\sources\jdv10-4\j2ee\home\applications\MyApp.ear begins...
10/11/30 12:00:47 oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.DeployerException: java.lang.InstantiationException: Unable to find/read file META-INF/application.xml in D:\sources\jdv10-4\j2ee\home\applications\MyApp (META-INF/application.xml)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.ApplicationDeployer.initArchive(ApplicationDeployer.java:420)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.ApplicationDeployer.doDeploy(ApplicationDeployer.java:190)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.DeployerBase.execute(DeployerBase.java:93)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at oracle.oc4j.admin.jmx.server.mbeans.deploy.OC4JDeployerRunnable.doRun(OC4JDeployerRunnable.java:52)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at oracle.oc4j.admin.jmx.server.mbeans.deploy.DeployerRunnable.run(DeployerRunnable.java:81)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
10/11/30 12:00:47 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Unable to find/read file META-INF/application.xml in D:\sources\jdv10-4\j2ee\home\applications\MyApp (META-INF/application.xml)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at com.evermind.naming.ContextUtils.readFromContext(ContextUtils.java:560)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at com.evermind.server.J2EEComponent.init(J2EEComponent.java:146)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at com.evermind.server.deployment.EnterpriseArchive.<init>(EnterpriseArchive.java:265)
10/11/30 12:00:47   at oracle.oc4j.admin.internal.ApplicationDeployer.initArchive(ApplicationDeployer.java:415)
10/11/30 12:00:47   ... 6 more
2010-11-30 12:00:47.164 NOTIFICATION Application Deployer for MyApp FAILED.
```

Comment: if you come with a solution I would like to know it...cause for me it was working fine for 3-4 months and suddenly my project out of the blue gives me the same errors. If I deploy the application manually it works just fine, but its anti-productive

Comment: For now, It deploys twice and fail once.. and I am going just fine with that.. BTW, I hear about `oracle enterprise pack for eclipse` but I never tried yet. I think that there's no version for 10.1.3.4 that I am using.... (I didn't do much extensive search about that)

Comment: thank you very much...i did a search and found the pack...Ill try it later on and I hope it wont mess things. The good thing is that it also supports weblogic which will probably come in handy.

Comment: I have seen that kind of errors also when the redeployment was done via OC4J enterprise manager. It always happens on Windows machines. I guess there is something that holds open the application directory or one of the files underneath (it might be even OC4J itself). As a result OC4J can't undeploy the old version of the application.

Comment: I've oracle enterprise pack for eclipse and I came across the same problem too. Do somebody find a solution?